# Bukkit timer speeds up as players join

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I have created a Bukkit runnable timer that counts up which all players will see on their scoreboard when the game has started, but I noticed that for every player that joins the timer goes up by 2. I have no clue how to fix this, suggestions? I have been searching around everywhere without finding a fix for this.

InGame class:

```
public class InGame extends BukkitRunnable implements Listener{

    private Main main;

    public InGame(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

    }

    public static int time;

    public void run() {
        if (time == 300) {
            if (GameState.getCurrentGamestate() == GameState.INGAME) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§b5 " + "§6minutes has passed!");
                for(Player all : main.players) {
                    all.playSound(all.getLocation(), Sound.NOTE_PLING, 1, 1);
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        if(time == 6000) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§b10 " + "§6minutes has passed!");
            for(Player all : main.players) {
                all.playSound(all.getLocation(), Sound.NOTE_PLING, 1, 1);

            }

        }
        if(time == 12000) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§b20 " + "§6minutes has passed!");
            for(Player all : main.players) {
                all.playSound(all.getLocation(), Sound.NOTE_PLING, 1, 1);

            }

        }
        if(time == 18000) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Main.prefix + "§b30 " + "§6minutes has passed!");
            for(Player all : main.players) {
                all.playSound(all.getLocation(), Sound.NOTE_PLING, 1, 1);

            }

        }

        time += 1;
    }
}
```

Main class code:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

//int minutes = Waiting.timeUntilStart / 60;
//int seconds = Waiting.timeUntilStart % 60;
//String t = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

public static Plugin plugin;
public static Main main;

ArrayList<UUID> player = new ArrayList();

public File file;
public FileConfiguration locationConfig;



public static int startCountdownId;
public static int startCounterId;

private int waitingtask;
private int count = 120;
private int number = 15;



public ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<Player> spectators = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<Player> innocent = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList<Player> traitor = new ArrayList();



public static Map<Location, Inventory> chests = new HashMap<Location, Inventory>();

public static String prefix = "§8§l┃ §6TIMV §8┃ §6";

Inventory spec;




public void onEnable() {



    Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world").setTime(300);

    startCountdown();
    saveDefaultConfig();
    registerFile();

    GameState.setGamestate(GameState.WAITING);
    plugin = this;
    registerEvents();

    Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("§cPlugin developed by InfernoArtz & Kodepus");

    this.getCommand("timv").setExecutor(new TimvCommand(this));
    //this.getCommand("role").setExecutor(new RoleCommand(this));
}

public void loc1() {
    Location loc = (Location) main.locationConfig.get("main.spawns.Lobby");
}



public void onDisable() {
    plugin = null;

}

/* SCOREBOARD KODER */
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    final Player p = e.getPlayer();

    new BukkitRunnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            final org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard s = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
            p.setScoreboard(s);
            final Objective o = s.registerNewObjective("sidebar", "dummy");
            if (p == null || !p.isOnline() || GameState.getCurrentGamestate() != GameState.WAITING) {
                cancel();

                return;
            } else {

            }



            o.setDisplayName("§bTIMV §3" + Waiting.timeUntilStart);
            o.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
            o.getScore(" ").setScore(12);
            o.getScore("§6§lRole").setScore(11);
            o.getScore("§fUnknown").setScore(10);
            o.getScore("   ").setScore(9);
            o.getScore("§a§lPlayers Left").setScore(8);
            o.getScore("§f" + Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size()).setScore(7);
            o.getScore("    ").setScore(6);
            o.getScore("§b§lRound Stats").setScore(5);
            o.getScore("§7Karma: §f0").setScore(4);
            o.getScore("          ").setScore(3);
            o.getScore("§8§m--------").setScore(2);
            o.getScore("§6play.§eserver§6.com").setScore(1);

        } 
    }.runTaskTimer(this, 1, 20);
}



public void registerFile() {
    file = new File(getDataFolder(), "locations.yml");
    locationConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
    saveFile();
}

public void saveFile() {
    try {
        locationConfig.save(file);

    } catch(IOException e) {


    }
}




public void registerEvents()
{


  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents((this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new JoinEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new QuitEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerInteractEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PvpEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new FallEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new InventoryEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new LobbyEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockPlace(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BreakEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DeathEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new LoginEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new HungerEvent(this), this);
  Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new NoMobSpawn(this), this);


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void startCountdown() {
    Waiting.timeUntilStart = 300;
    startCountdownId = getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Waiting(this), 20l, 20l);



    }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void startCounter() {
    InGame.time = 0;
    startCounterId = getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new InGame(this), 20l, 20l);


}

public void stopCountdown() {
    getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(startCountdownId);
}

public void restartCountdown() {
    startCountdown();
    stopCountdown();
}

public static Main getPlugin() {
    return main;
}










   }
```

Comment: `public static int time;` You're sharing a timer for all players.

Comment: Dont think thats the problem here

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Look up what `static` does.

Comment: Howd I make it work in Main then?

Comment: By not using it statically. At all.

Comment: The problem is not using static. Please show more code, such as your PlayerLoginEvent or how you're registering the timer for each player

Comment: You can have a static counter, as I suppose that the timer should be the same for all the players, not a timer for each player. Therefore the timer should be static.

Comment: You're likely running this `run` method once for each player, and then you're increasing the timer by one for each player. We need more code to be able to identify that, please.

Comment: I edited the post and added the full main class code

Comment: Btw you calculated the seconds wrong in your timer. When your check for 10 minutes is true, actually 100 minutes have passed. Same factor of x10 for 20 and 30 minutes. And I agree that you should get rid of static since plugins like this should support multiarena, thus you need to be able to run several counters at the same time.

Comment: Yes I see, but Im running this as bungeecord

Comment: Can I see your PlayerJoinEvent, @InfernoArtz?

Comment: It is in the main class @Kerooker

Answer (score 1):

So you are making a Runnable for every player that joins, and then you add +1 to your timer in every Runnable. So if there joined 12 players, there are 12 Runnable's each second, so it adds 12 times +1 second to the timer each second.

To solve this, do not let control an event your game thread. Control it in a solid way without using any event. Use the events only to control the ArrayLists with players and check the ArrayLists in your threads.

If you are using multiple threads which access something in one of the threads, you should use the synchronized keyword. I suggest you dive into that.

I've made a small example for this, I hope this will make it more clear.

the Main class:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

   public ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

   // My HashMap with the threads
   private HashMap<BukkitTask, Integer> game = new HashMap<>();

   public void onEnable() {
      this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

      // Create a thread here and let it run the whole game
      BukkitTask task = new Game(this).runTaskTimer(this,1,20);
      game.put(task, task.getTaskId());
   }

   public void onDisable() {
   }

   // Eventhandlers that control the ArrayList with players
   @EventHandler
   public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
      Player player = e.getPlayer();
      this.players.add(player);
      if (!this.players.contains(player)) {
         this.players.add(player);
      }
   }

   @EventHandler
   public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
      Player player = e.getPlayer();
      if (!this.players.contains(player)) {
         this.players.remove(player);
      }
   }
}
```

my Game() extends BukkitRunnable class:

```
public class Game extends BukkitRunnable {

   private Main main;

   private int time;

   public Game(Main main) {
      this.main = main;
   }

   public void run() {
      for(Player player : main.players) {
         final org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard s = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
         player.setScoreboard(s);
         final Objective o = s.registerNewObjective("sidebar", "dummy");

         o.setDisplayName("Sidebar");
         o.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
         o.getScore("Time: " + this.time).setScore(12);
      }

      // Don't count if there are no players
      if (!main.players.isEmpty()) {
         this.time++;
      }
   }
}
```

You can create more BukkitRunnables like the Game() class, but be sure to use `synchronized` when needed, this makes it thread-safe.

A shoutout to [hnefatl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193020/hnefatl) for giving me the right way to do this. If there are any better options, I'd like to hear them in the comments.

Comment: This is a better design, but not ideal - if a client connects, disconnects, then reconnects, you'll end up with 2 `Runnable`s running. It would be better to just always have a `Runnable` sending status information to all the players - if there aren't any players, then it just doesn't need to do anything. You might also need to add some synchronisation logic, this code isn't thread-safe. It doesn't matter if the `onJoin` events can only be fired synchronously, but otherwise it definitely does.

Comment: @hnefatl So there should be an OnPlayerQuitEvent which removes the player from the ArrayList and check for the last player and quits the Runnable? Please correct me at all time if I am wrong, I am still a learner too. Thanks for the comment, it is really helpful

Comment: Handling a "player quit" event is necessary to keep track of which players are connected in the `ArrayList`, yeah - but the main point is not to spawn the thread on a condition that could be met multiple times. Keep it running *all the time* (on a timer) and each time, just iterate over all the players and send the scoreboard. If there are no players, connected, then you'll just iterate over "no players" and its fine.